# Referencing cells with index

Tags: vba, reference

Im struggling with probably an easy issue but google isnt helping me.

```
    With Worksheets("Fake").Range("A5:BE5")
    Set GrandTotal = .Find("Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not GrandTotal Is Nothing Then
        GrandTotal = GrandTotal.Address
        GrandTotalColumn = Range(GrandTotal).Column
        GrandTotalColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, GrandTotalColumn + 1).Address, "$")(1)
        Debug.Print GrandTotal
        Debug.Print GrandTotalColumn
        Debug.Print GrandTotalColumnLetter
    End If
    End With


    Cells(9, GrandTotalColumn + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-21]="""","""",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""total"",RC[-21])),"""",RC[-22]))"

    Cells(9, GrandTotalColumn + 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Debug.Print GrandTotalColumnLetter
    With Worksheets("Fake")
    .Range(.Cells(9, GrandTotalColumn + 1), .Cells(10000, GrandTotalColumn + 1)).Select
'ERROR HERE
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    .Range(.Cells(9, GrandTotalColumn + 1), .Cells(10000, GrandTotalColumn + 1)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
```

But obviously its not working... How do i reference this..?
I've tried also getting the "GrandTotalColumnLetter", but i still dont know how to insert it in a Range to select, even though i know how to get the column number and letter..

Comment: (Not my DV) but I really suggest you read up on how to do `Range` and `Cell` references. You've got 3 arguments in `Cells`.

Comment: Use `offset` ...

Comment: `GrandTotal = GrandTotal.Address` makes no sense as one is a range and the other is a string, plus this line is unnecessary.

Comment: Im just not quite sure what is the correct way to even google this. What i have is a dynamic column and a static set of rows. Therefore i try locating the dynamic column but now that i have located it, i cant seem to find out how to use my column index number with multiple rows..

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem. You don't need to copy/pastespecial. Just write the formula to the *entire* range in one step. Then you can call `.Value = .Value` on that same range.

Comment: Well, two things with this: This doesnt quite solve the how to reference a dynamic column. The other thing is that i dont really know how to modify the current code (recorded on that part" to insert the formula to a larger range..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It finds the range object that "Grant Total" is in then uses the column attribute to select the range next to it (1 column to the right). I kept GrandTotal as a range so your test still works the same way.

Okay, I edited this to include your new code.
This works to put fromula into the column from row 9 to row 10,000 
You really don;t need to do all the selecting and copy and pasting like that, but here is your code.
Problem was that you were putting the formula in the "activecell" after selecting a range from row 1 to 10,000, it only put the formula in row one, not row 9.

```
With Worksheets("Fake")
    Set GrandTotal = .Range("A5:BE5").Find("Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not GrandTotal Is Nothing Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, GrandTotal.Column + 1), .Cells(10000, GrandTotal.Column + 1)).Select

    End If
End With


    Cells(9, GrandTotal.Column + 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-21]="""","""",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""total"",RC[-21])),"""",RC[-22]))"

    Cells(9, GrandTotal.Column + 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Debug.Print GrandTotalColumnLetter
    With Worksheets("Fake")
    .Range(.Cells(1, GrandTotal.Column + 1), .Cells(10000, GrandTotal.Column + 1)).Select
'ERROR HERE
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    .Range(.Cells(9, GrandTotal.Column + 1), .Cells(10000, GrandTotal.Column + 1)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
```

Comment: Hi, i updated the entire part of the code up. I used what you did above, but i get the Run-time error 1004, Select method of Range class failed. Basicly i have the same variables as you do and i did it inside the With - End With, but still doesnt work

Comment: You can only select a range if its worksheet is active (not that you probably need to select it).

Comment: The worksheet is active, because the  Cells(9, GrandTotalColumn + 1).Select actually selects the right worksheet's cell.

Comment: I didn't rewrite all your code, but this could have been done with just a few lines.  If Grand Total is not found, you wil have a lot of errors popping up.